# Blackberry 10 sdk QML - Changing value of button outside listview

Tags: blackberry, qml, blackberry-10

I'm trying to build a soundboard in the blackberry 10 SDK using QML

My buttons are created using a listview and XML file

I'm trying to enable the stop button when you click on the button in the listview
but it doesn't do anything.

The stop button is outside the listview because i want it at the top at all times

Can anyone help me solve this problem I'm new to blackberry SDK and QML

Thank you very much

**Error i get in console:**
Can't find variable: button

```
I've resolved this problem
```

see link below

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/QML-Accessing-variables-defined-outside-a-list-component-from/m-p/1786265#M641

Comment: Can you please answer your own question, and accept it when the option is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the problem for me

Link:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/QML-Accessing-variables-defined-outside-a-list-component-from/m-p/1786265#M641